# NoMethodError: private method `CSV' called for

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have the rspec test like this:

```
describe "POST import" do
    describe "handling CSV files" do
      describe "to import products" do
        before(:each) do
          @import = Hotel.create! valid_attributes
          @import.CSV.stub(:foreach).with("file_path", headers: true).and_return(data)
        end

        it "should process the csv file after save" do
          @import.should_receive(:process_csv)
          @import.save
        end

        it "should load the csv file" do
          CSV.should_receive(:foreach)
          @import.save
        end
      end
    end   
  end
```

When I run test command, the errors were showed here:

```
Failure/Error: @import.CSV.stub(:foreach).with("file_path", headers: true).and_return(data)
     NoMethodError:
       private method `CSV' called for #<Hotel:0xbaf96108>
```

I write these codes to test my csv upload function, please show me where is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `CSV.stub` instead of `@import.CSV`.

Comment: another error occured: `undefined local variable or method 'data' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_7::Nested_1::N
ested_1:0xba6be97c>`

Comment: Yes, you say `and_return(data)`, but data is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @Arienjan I removed `and_return(data)` and other error: `Failure/Error: CSV.should_receive(:foreach)#.any_number_of_times
       (<CSV (class)>).foreach(any args)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments`